# Securing a text file in a website folder

Tags: php, security

I have several folders in my website directory which contains textfiles called "secure.txt".
For security reasons the URL of these files are never shown in the webbrowser but my website searches for these files (PHP code), which contains sensitive information.

How can I make the PHP code allowed to read these files but restrain access through the url, so a potential hacker wouldn't be able to read the content of these files?

Answer (score 2):

put them out side your document root folder and place the following .htaccess file in the folder you want to protect. Also if you don't want to access it through a particular IP remove the last line.

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.0
```

[EDIT:]
To allow php scripts, etc. allow localhost (127.0.0.1)

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I tried this and sure enough i can't type in the url for the file and get access to it. However, the php script on the website can't neither, which is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should put them in another folder and make the .htaccess deny from all, allow from 127.0.0.1

Comment: Would that work for the sub-folders of that directory as well?

Answer (score 1):

Old trick for that: Prefix the files with `<?php die("I'm a fraid I can't do that, Jim"); ?>`, and call them `*.php`. On parsing, ignore the prefix.

**Edit**

Why do this? The rationale behind it is, that you avoid a dependency on some special webserver configuration, which acn be forgotten (on moving to a new server), unavailable (many cheap hosts don't give you .htaccess), not applicable to some webserver software (IIS) etc.

So the reasoning is to trade some computational overhead against flexibility, portability and platform independence.

Comment: I like this idea! I just have one problem with it. The PHP code which reads the file can't get the information out of the file now and therefore can't store the info i want to a variable... It happens as soon as i put in the <? ?> tags.

Comment: This is what I meant with `On parsing, ignore the prefix.` - you need to adapt the PHP code: It will likely have something like `$txt=file_get_contents($path);` - immediately after that you need something like `$txt=substr(strstr($txt,'?>'),2)`

Comment: It doesn't work... I really like the idea though. I can see how it should work, but as soon as thoose ?> tags are in the file it just doesn't...

Comment: @Zahrec Will need some knowledge of the parsing code and file structure, I guess it's quite easy. Do you use `file_get_contents()` or `fread()` or whatever?

Comment: Thanks for your help. My web host won't allow .htaccess override... This is how i read the file:                                    $infoFile = fopen("$filepath", "r");
$contents = stream_get_contents($infoFile);

Comment: OK, **after** `$contents = stream_get_contents($infoFile);` we have more in `$contents` than we want, so we cut off the prefix. Easiest way: Use a prefix of known length (my example has $prefixlen=49), then insert `$content=substr($content,$prefixlen)`

Comment: I try doing that with the length I have "32". Then as a test i use var_dump() on the $contents but it returns bool(false).

Comment: 1. use `var_dump()` **before** the `substr()` to make sure you have the correct value there, 2. if this turns out to be bad too, replace `$infoFile = fopen("$filepath", "r"); $contents = stream_get_contents($infoFile);` with `$contents = file_get_contents($filepath);`

Comment: Thanks for your patience. It still does not work. Either way it doesn't work. The var_dump which is right after the file_get_contents just returns everything before the ?> ending tag. Nothing behinds it is read to the file. Could you perhaps make your code public by answering my question? I test the site on MAMP...

Answer (score 0):

Can you move them out of your website directory altogether? If so, then make sure PHP has access to that directory! (The `open_basedir` value will need to include it.)

Comment: I don't think that my web-host company allow me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest moving the files out of the webroot to be on the safe side

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, deny access to all files named `secure.txt` from within `httpd.conf`:

```
<Files secure.txt>
  deny from all
</Files>
```

You may do the same via `.htaccess` files as well (if your server is configured to allow override access rights from htaccess).

But a better solution would be to include the sensitive information into your PHP scripts themselves, or to store it in a database.